# emitter.emit that returns a promise, and waits for its listeners

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, promise

I have an event emitter, and listeners that register to it. I want the `emit` to return a promise that resolves after all the listeners resolve (if they return a promise). Something like:

```
emitter.on('my_event', function(data) {
    return asyncStuff(); // returns a promise
});

emitter.on('my_event', function(data) {
    return moreAsyncStuff(); // returns a promise
});

emitter.emit('my_event', {some_data: 'bla'}).then(function () {
    // this happens after both promises from the above listeners resolve
});
```

And ideally, I would also like to get back the results of the resolved promises, like the `all` function:

```
emitter.emit('my_event', {some_data: 'bla'}).all(function (resultsArr) {
    // resultsArr contains the results of the promises from the listeners
});
```

Is there a library / node module that does this? Or some clever way to do it with minimal code?

Comment: The eventEmitter object does not provide any access to what a listener returns so you can't do what you're asking the way you're asking.  In fact the return value from a listener is simply not used at all by the `eventEmitter` object - it just doesn't pay attention to it at all.  You will have to rethink how you're trying to solve your problem. Per the doc,  `.emit()` returns `true` or `false` based on whether there were any listeners.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your comment. To clarify - I was not asking specifically about the accepted `emitter` spec (although sticking to the spec has it's obvious advantages). I'm looking for a solution in the form of a npm module or library that provides the feature I described.